# What happens if I modify yolo annotation .txt files during training?

Tags: computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

Will it recognize the changes, will it have saved the annotation data prior to training, or will it cause an error?

Have not attempted yet, will expect it to recognize the changes while training. Don't want to break the training.